# For-loop in a tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: for-loop, multidimensional-array, tensorflow, vectorization, tensor

I am new to tensorflow, I want to make a tensor using a number of if-else conditions. I just don't know how to do it.

In python, if a tensor is like `[3,3,3]`, I can use `for` loop just like below:

```
for i in range(3):
   for j in range(3):
      for k in range(3):
         if tensor[i,j,k]>10:
            tensor[i,j,k]=tensor[i,j,k]-10
         elif tensor[i,j,k]<4:
            tensor[i,j,k]=tensor[i,j,k]+60
```

After this I still want to calculate loos functions by using tensor and then go next loop for training.
Does anyone know how to do this?
I know how to do this in a single way within a session. But I don't know how to do this in a training loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Tensorflow way

You particular example is easily vectorizable, so there is no real need to do it via for-loop. Here's pure tensorflow solution:

```py
x = tf.placeholder(shape=[3, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
cond1 = tf.where(x > 10, x - 10, tf.zeros_like(x))
cond2 = tf.where(x < 4, x + 60, tf.zeros_like(x))
cond3 = tf.where(tf.logical_and(x >= 4, x <= 10), x, tf.zeros_like(x))
y = cond1 + cond2 + cond3
```

### `py_func` way

If by chance you have to do fine-grained processing, you can always fall back to [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func):

```py
def process(tensor):
  mask1 = tensor > 10
  mask2 = tensor < 4
  tensor[mask1] -= 10
  tensor[mask2] += 60
  return tensor
z = tf.py_func(process, [x], tf.float32)
```

### Combining it all together

A complete runnable example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(shape=[3, 3], dtype=tf.float32)

cond1 = tf.where(x > 10, x - 10, tf.zeros_like(x))
cond2 = tf.where(x < 4, x + 60, tf.zeros_like(x))
cond3 = tf.where(tf.logical_and(x >= 4, x <= 10), x, tf.zeros_like(x))
y = cond1 + cond2 + cond3

def process(tensor):
  mask1 = tensor > 10
  mask2 = tensor < 4
  tensor[mask1] -= 10
  tensor[mask2] += 60
  return tensor
z = tf.py_func(process, [x], tf.float32)

sample = [[10, 15, 25], [1, 2, 3], [4, 4, 10]]
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: sample}))
  print(sess.run(z, feed_dict={x: sample}))
```

Output:

```py
[[10.  5. 15.]
 [61. 62. 63.]
 [ 4.  4. 10.]]
[[10.  5. 15.]
 [61. 62. 63.]
 [ 4.  4. 10.]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot, but i still get a question that i still have a lot calculation to do with tensor X after execute y or z function. So, is there any way to use tensor X, before sess.run(y)?

Comment: I do not understand the question, as it sounds too broad now: you can do a lot of different things. The graph can be arbitrary large and `x` can have as many transformations as needed.

Comment: hold on, my problem is like this: firstly i get a image and apply it in a net then i got a tensor x, after that, i should do some threshold on x just like above and i got another tensor x1 and x2, then with x1 x2, i will do another calculation to get loss data, so in my own code, x1 x2 should be acquired in loss function calculation not an isolate function.

Comment: What do you mean by isolate functions? `y` and `z` are tensors and are part of computational graph, just like `x`: everything that can be done with `x` can also be apply to them.

Comment: The link to `tf.py_func` looks broken.